# Quickly jump to a letter in a ListView (like contacts)

Tags: listview, react-native

With React Native, is there a simple implementation or library of the jump to a letter section for a ListView, like how I can quickly jump to G contacts in Apple's contacts app?

Otherwise it looks like I'd have to build it myself with onPressIn, section headers, and something that can scroll to the right section (not sure how to do that yet)

Comment: DId any of the package worked for you from the suggested list ?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `@Wesley Gormley`'s answer, these are other libraries that you can try:

https://github.com/rgovindji/react-native-atoz-list
https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-alphabetlistview

Answer (score 0):

i havent used this, but even if it doesnt work specifically for you it might give you an idea on how to build it from scratch. [React-Native-Alphabetical-ListView](https://github.com/bozzmob/React-Native-Alphabetical-ListView)